# How do I use Closure Compiler with grunt-requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler, grunt-requirejs

This is from my Gruntfile:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      almond: true,
      optimize: 'closure',
      baseUrl: '<%= cfg.src %>/scripts',
      mainConfigFile: '<%= cfg.src %>/scripts/config.js',
      out: '<%= cfg.staticDist %>/scripts/all.js',
      deps: ['app', 'config', 'bluebird', 'jquery']
    }
  }
},
```

When I set `optimize` to `closure`, grunt-requirejs writes this to console:

```
Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task
>> Error: Error: optimizer with name of "closure" not found for this environment
>>     at Object.optimize.js (/Users/dan/Documents/Projects/test/node_modules/grunt-requirejs/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:24632:27)
```

Does grunt-requirejs support optimising with Closure Compiler? Where do I need to put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is that you want to use the more updated [`grunt-contrib-requirejs`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs/) without optimization.

Then use a grunt task like [`grunt-closure-tools`](https://github.com/closureplease/grunt-closure-tools) to optimize the combined files.

[I found a user on GitHub that has success with this.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs/issues/19#issuecomment-27350923)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I didn't realize before, but this makes perfect sense. Why do you say grunt-contrib-requirejs is more updated?

Comment: It's an official `grunt-contrib` task, so it's used by a lot more people. It might not be updated that much more, but it's used a lot.

Comment: thanks, good to know. I didn't realize `grunt-contrib` means official.

Answer (score 1):

As [Allan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21428346/458193) and [asciidisco confirmed](https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs/issues/70#issuecomment-33574197):

> We got rid of that. Caused too many troubles. Also, `r.js` only supports that (correct me if I´m wrong) if you´re in a rhino environment & because we are `node` only, we stick with uglify.
>
> If you really wan't to use Closure Compiler, I recommend to run the task with no minification & apply a task such as [grunt-closure-compiler](https://github.com/gmarty/grunt-closure-compiler) to the optimised files later in your process.